# Express: Getting full route parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm building a node.js application using express framework.
The app routes are defined in separate files, so basically I have one router per resource. Here's an example:

app.js

```
var fooRoutes = require('./fooRoutes.js');
...
router.use('/users/:id/foos',fooRoutes);
```

fooRoutes.js

```
var fooController = require('./../controllers/fooController.js');
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  fooController.getFoos(req, res);
});
```

fooController.js

```
var FooController = function() {
  this.getFoos = function(req, res) {
    var foos = [];
    fooService.findFoosByUser(req.params.id, function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(400, err);
      }
      res.send(200, recordset);
    });
  };
};
```

The problem is that I cannot get the `id` parameter from fooController. If I try to log it from the app file, I can get it. I guess it's because the route at that point recognizes it as a parameter.

Is there a way to get that parameter from `fooController`?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that express added a feature to merge parameters from parent routers. This can be found [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)

With this, I can solve it by declaring my router like this:

```
var router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
```